# How can I add an upload filetype to mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I would like to be able to upload .2h files to mediawiki.  I think it is version 1.310-alpha

I added '2h' to wgFileExtensions which almost works.
It now complains with:

```
File extension ".2h" does not match the detected MIME type of the file (application/sla).
```

The file is binary, so I assume I need to somehow allow:

```
application/octet-stream
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the [`includes/libs/mime/mime.types`](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/plugins/gitiles/mediawiki/core/+/master/includes/libs/mime/mime.types) file, add `.2h` to the line starting with `application/sla`, point [`$wgMimeTypeFile`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgMimeTypeFile) to that file.
(Or make sure the [mime detector](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgMimeDetectorCommand) does not detect `.2h` files as `application/sla`.)